# SPARQL query return arbitrary set of objects

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web

I have some data that contains a property `hasNextSibling`.  I would like to be able to query for an arbitrary set of the siblings.  I can easily get all the siblings following a specific point, but how can I retrieve the siblings between X and Y.

For example, the data model is of the children of Old-Lady-in-the-Shoe. Some siblings in order are Fred, Brandy, Chris, Zack, Emma, Brad [and so on].  The list is much longer of course.  I want the ability to say "give me all the siblings from Brandy to Emma" - returning Brandy, Chris, Zack, Emma.

I would have a query something like :

```
SELECT ?name WHERE {
    ?kid rdfs:label 'Brandy' .
    ?kid local:hasNextSibling+ ?sib .
    ?sib rdfs:label ?name .
    // this is where I need to stop if ?name = 'Emma'
    // but the graph still needs to complete and return all the other siblings
}
```

I can not simply filter for `?name` less than my ending name because the labels (names) are not in any determinable or natural order (hence the need for the hasNextSibling property to maintain the order).

Comment: SPARQL first generated the whole list and then filters it. So your filter will be performed after the query has been executed. What exactly do you think is the problem?

Comment: "hence the need for the sibling property"  Do you mean that the order is implicit in the hasNextSibling property?  E.g., firstSibling hasNextSibling secondSibling . secondSibling hasNextSibling thirdSibling, etc?  For what it's worth, some of the confusion would have been avoided if the example siblings weren't ordered alphabetically.

Comment: Edited the example to hopefully clarify why it is not possible to perform a simple filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you've got data like this, with kids with labels and a hasNextSibling property:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:> .

:a :label 'a' ; :hasNextSibling :b .
:b :label 'b' ; :hasNextSibling :c .
:c :label 'c' ; :hasNextSibling :d .
:d :label 'd' ; :hasNextSibling :e .
:e :label 'e' ; :hasNextSibling :f .
:f :label 'f' ; :hasNextSibling :g .
:g :label 'g' .
```

Using property paths, you can search for kids that have a backward hasNextSibling chain to the first in the range that you want and a forward hasNextSibling chain to the last in the range that you want:

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?kid ?label where {
  ?kid ^:hasNextSibling* [:label 'b'] ;
       :hasNextSibling* [:label 'd'] ;
       :label ?label .
}
```

```
---------------
| kid | label |
===============
| :b  | "b"   |
| :c  | "c"   |
| :d  | "d"   |
---------------
```

If you want either of those to be exclusive ranges, you can use a `+` property path instead of a `*` property path.

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?kid ?label where {
  ?kid ^:hasNextSibling+ [:label 'b'] ;
       :hasNextSibling+ [:label 'f'] ;
       :label ?label .
}
```

```
---------------
| kid | label |
===============
| :c  | "c"   |
| :d  | "d"   |
| :e  | "e"   |
---------------
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to accomplish the same in SPARQL 1.0?

Comment: @WayneWeibel There are no property paths in SPARQL 1.0 (at least, it's not part of the standard; some implementations may have property paths, but not the rest of the SPARQL 1.1, so it doesn't hurt to check the particular implementation that you're using), so this approach won't work.  I don't think there's a way to do this in SPARQL 1.0 with the data structured as you have it.